# prove that if $X$ is skew- symmetric matrix of order $n$ and$(X^2+I_n)$ is non singular then $(iX+I_n)^{-1} +I_n$ is unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

I know the basics definition of the unitary, skew-symmetric and invertible matrix but still, I'm not able to prove this statement,

Note: computation is over a field of char $3$.

prove that if $X$ is skew-symmetric matrix of order $n$ and$(X^2+I_n)$ is non-singular then $(iX+I_n)^{-1} +I_n$ is a unitary matrix. Unitary matrix means $UU^T=I$ besides $UU^*=I$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this example fail the condition that X is skew-symmetric matrix

Comment: Even simpler, $X=0$ is skew, but $2I$ is not unitary.

Comment: sorry, there is one more condition in this statement that, here the field is $Z_3$ all computation over $Z_3$

Comment: $(2iI)^* = -2iI $.

Comment: Ah come on. That is huge.

Comment: I totally agree with you but I tried  many times and I don't get it  so please any help

Comment: Have you tried just multiplying and expanding. Then factor $(I+X^2)^{-1}$ out. That is, show $U^*U = I$ where $U$ is the matrix above.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you

Comment: @Mathematicslearner, Are you sure you want X to be skew and not just symmetric? Because it seems like you want to have $(I+iX)^{\dagger}=(I-iX)$, but for skew-symmetric matrix it is $(I+iX)^\dagger=(I+iX)$.

Comment: @user1551 In the given statement its "field of characteristic 3" I thought let's put it particularly example as $Z_3$ is a field of char 3

Comment: okay, thanks a lot @user1551 this is useful for me.

Comment: @user1551 I'm a beginner in this field and now I think I understand the statement properly if in the above problem unitary matrix is over a field of char $0$ and all other calculations of over field of char $3$ then the above statement is valid.

Comment: @user1551 can you please give some easy explain why 'i' is not $\sqrt -1$ and for the field now I'm still confused i  think i think some more time for field in the paper.

Comment: @uer1551 because usually, we study matrix over the field $R$ or $C$ as per my understanding. whose char is $0$, also for some particular matrix  is defined only over the unique field as matrix is directly related with linear transformations

Comment: you edited your post in the last day but for some reason it still says $X$ is *skew* and as the answer from more than a week ago shows, this is wrong.  I can give the *symmetric* $X$ proof, but I increasingly suspect it won't help. The real issue is you need to study $\mathbb F_3$ and $\mathbb F_3[t]/(t^2+1)$.  If you know basic ring theory that is probably enough for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to understand. I suppose that you mean, if $X\in M_n(\mathbb Z_3)$ is skew-symmetric, $X^2+I$ is nonsingular and $i$ is a square root of $-1$ in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Z_3$, then
$$
U=(iX+I)^{-1}+I\in M_n(\mathbb Z_3[i])
$$
is unitary in the sense that $U^\ast U=I$.

**This is true only if $X=0$.**

Note that $U^\ast=\left[(iX+I)^{-1}+I\right]^\ast=(-iX^T+I)^{-1}+I=(iX+I)^{-1}+I=U$. Thus
\begin{align}
U^\ast U-I
&=U^2-I\\
&=\left[(iX+I)^{-1}+I\right]^2-I\\
&=(iX+I)^{-2}+2(iX+I)^{-1}\\
&=(iX+I)^{-2}-(iX+I)^{-1}\\
&=(iX+I)^{-1}\left[(iX+I)^{-1}-I\right].\tag{1}\\
\end{align}
Since $X^2+I=(iX+I)(-iX+I)$ is nonsingular, $iX+I$ is nonsingular. Therefore, if $UU^\ast=I$, then from $(1)$ we obtain $(iX+I)^{-1}-I=0$. Hence $iX+I=I$, meaning that $X$ is necessarily zero.

Comment: I was just about to type this up... though I inferred the field was $\mathbb K\cong \mathbb F_3[t]/(t^2+1)$.  If $X$'s scalars live in the ground field then being 'unitary' is the same as being involutive, which implies $U-I$ is idempotent and invertible hence $(iX+I) = I$ but obviously many other skew symmetric matrices than 0 'work' to give a contradiction.  I think OP meant for $X$ to be symmetric not skew.

Comment: @user8675309 Isn't $\mathbb F_3[i]=\mathbb F_3(i)$ by rationalisation? Anyway, you are right. $X$ should be symmetric, not skew-symmetric. If you write up an answer, I think it will be helpful to the OP.

Comment: Indeed $ \mathbb F_3[t]/(t^2+1)\cong \mathbb F_3[i]=\mathbb F_3(i)$. I'll write up the symmetric $X$ case today.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U=(\iota X+I_n)^{-1}+I_n$ and for any matrix $(A^{-1})^T=(A^T)^{-1}.$
then  $U^T=(-\iota X+I_n)^{-1}+I_n$.
Now consider
\begin{equation}
    UU^T=[(\iota X+I_n)^{-1}+I_n][(-\iota X+I_n)^{-1}+I_n]
\end{equation}
$$ =(\iota X+I_n)^{-1}(-\iota X+I_n)^{-1}+(\iota X+I_n)^{-1}+(-\iota X+I_n)^{-1}+I$$
$$=[(-\iota X+I_n)(\iota X+I_n)]^{-1}+(\iota X+I_n)^{-1}+(-\iota X+I_n)^{-1}+I$$
as $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$
so, eq.(1) becomes,
\begin{equation}
    =(X^2+I)^{-1}+(\iota X+I_n)^{-1}+(-\iota X+I_n)^{-1}+I
\end{equation}

multiply both side of eq.(2) by $(X^2+I) $ we get RHS as
$=I+(\iota X +I)(-\iota X +I)(\iota X +I)^{-1}+(\iota X +I)(-\iota X +I)(-\iota X +I)^{-1}+(X^2+I)$
then eq.(1)become,
(note that $(\iota X +I)$ and $(-\iota X+ I)$ are both with commuted each other.)
$$(x^2+I_n)UU^T=I_n+(-\iota X+I_n)+(\iota X+I_n)+(X^2+I_n)$$
$$UU^T=(I_n+X^2)^{-1}(4I_n+X^2)=I_n$$ as $4\equiv 1\pmod 3.$